# Do I lose reputation if I answer a downvoted question?

Tags: support, reputation, down-votes

Do I lose reputation if I am answering a downvoted question?

Comment: You can read the help page for more information

Comment: No, BUT there are users who, if they believe a question is bad, will downvote answers to that question to indicate that they think it's a bad idea to answer bad questions, and also to make it easier to delete such questions.

Answer (score 6):

No. You only lose reputation for downvoting answer, or having your questions or answers downvoted. Answering questions is the core function in Stack Exchange, and you won't lose any reputation whether the question is downvoted or not.

Comment: It might be noteworthy to add that questions that tend to net a lot of downvotes are PSQs and the other types of problems that tend to get eventually closed and/or deleted. If deleted, you will lose the rep from your answer. In that light, if you're concerned about your rep, it might not be a good idea to answer questions that are accumulating a lot of downvotes/close votes, since your effort may be ultimately wasted (again, on the premise your concern is solely with rep).

Comment: @EeveeTrainer Actually, even for people not concerned too much about rep, they may not wish to spend a lot of time & effort answering questions if their answer will be deleted some time later. It could definitely help the OP, and perhaps other people, for a while, but it won't have the long term value of adding to the knowledge base here that would occur if the question/answer wasn't deleted. Also, I myself generally prefer to not answer PSQs, or to just give minimal hints/answers if I do, to avoid encouraging those types of questions, as I prefer the OPs to show some context/effort.

Comment: @John what is PSQ? I think answering those questions are still beneficial to you, because bad questions usually contain implicit assumptions that need to be revealed. The job of the answerers is to help the asker to realize these assumptions. So even if the answers are gone, the answerers can know what assumptions novices likely to have, and be prepared for the next one.

Comment: @Ooker PSQ is short for "Problem Statement Question" that's basically just a question of a problem statement, such as word for word from a book or assignment, with no context given, e.g., what, if anything, in particular the user is unsure of, what the person's tried (& possibly had difficulty with), where the question comes from, etc. A site as relatively large as this has a diverse set of users & opinions, but I believe a fairly general consensus is we want to be careful with PSQs as we don't want to become a "homework site" where people expect us to just do their homework for them.

Comment: @Ooker As for how to handle PSQs, I believe there is generally less agreement, such as in terms of closing & answering them. Some people believe it's best to just always close them, while others believe that, if they believe the OP (Original Poster) is sincere but just has done a poor job asking, they should give a hint or start of an answer, enough to help prod the OP to solve the problem themselves. As for myself, I tend more to the former than the latter, but as with most things in life, each situation is somewhat unique.

Comment: @John I see. My previous comment is meant for unclear or too broad questions, that makes you see it wrong in so many ways, but unable to tell exactly where it's wrong

Comment: @Ooker As for answering PSQs also helping me, such as "implicit assumptions that need to be revealed", I can determine a lot of that just by reading the question itself. To the extent that answering, including getting feedback, will help in this way, I can also get a lot of that from answering relativelyh well-asked questions, where the OP has shown they've done some work, have thought carefully about what they don't know (& sometimes what they do), with this resulting in them asking a fairly good question that, quite often, I enjoy more answering.

Comment: @Ooker You're correct, "unclear or too broad" questions aren't quite the same thing, especially the "too broad" part. However, the wording here of "unclear" is quite often used with PSQ's, even if they're stated clearly, in addition to questions where it's sometimes hard to tell what the OP is actually asking about. As for answering questions which are "too broad", I agree this could have certain benefits if it causes me to think of things in a different way, including things like the perception the question is "too broad". Also, as you state below, we may wish to get clarification if unclear.

Comment: yes I agree. It's enjoying to answer well-put questions. I just want to focus more on unclear ones, because usually they are also the ones OPs put effort in, but still receive negative votes. This brings confusion and frustration for both sides to communicate with each other